# SLD file with .png's to style points on a Geoserver OpenLayers map

Tags: geoserver, sld

The .png's are stored here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.12.1\data_dir\styles`.

I have seen many different ways to incorporate a .png into Geoserver and none have worked for me. I have no idea how to proceed.

These are a few formats that I have tried:

1. `xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/styles/Switch.png"`
2. `xlink: "Switch.png"`
3. `xlink:href="http://10.29.6.112:8080/geoserver/styles/Switch.png"`

Does anyone have any advice or suggestions?

P.S. I am working from IP 10.29.6.112.

Answer (score 1):

The filepath should refer to the local file on the server, so similar to

```
<se:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" 
   xlink:href="file://C:/Program Files (x86)/GeoServer 2.12.1/data_dir/styles/Switch.png"/>
```

If the style is linked to a workspace, I believe the relative reference is based on `/geoserver_data/workspaces/workspaceName/styles/` and not on `/geoserver_data/styles/`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I placed the .png's in the folder you named above but unfortunately, the .png still will not display.

Comment: @MelBuske what does the log say?

Answer (score 0):

My working example. Below you can find config and label for point layer.

**Label Placement**

- AnchorPointX = move label left/right
- AnchorPointY = move label top/bottom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.1.0" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>Symbol</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>Symbol</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Symbol</se:Name>
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>0</se:MinScaleDenominator>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>3000000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:PointSymbolizer>
             <se:Graphic>
              <se:ExternalGraphic>
                <se:OnlineResource xlink:href="img/smile.png" xlink:type="simple"/>
                <se:Format>image/png</se:Format>
              </se:ExternalGraphic>
              <!--Plain SVG fallback, no parameters-->
              <se:ExternalGraphic>
                <se:OnlineResource xlink:href="img/smile.png" xlink:type="simple"/>
                <se:Format>image/png</se:Format>
              </se:ExternalGraphic>
              <!--Well known marker fallback-->
              <se:Mark>
                <se:WellKnownName>square</se:WellKnownName>
                <se:Fill>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#e8718d</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Fill>
                <se:Stroke>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>
              </se:Mark>
              <se:Size>21</se:Size>
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
            <se:Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>label_column</ogc:PropertyName>
            </se:Label>
            <se:Font>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Arial</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">14</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-weight">bold</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Font>
            <se:LabelPlacement>
              <se:PointPlacement>
                <se:AnchorPoint>
                  <se:AnchorPointX>0.5</se:AnchorPointX>
                  <se:AnchorPointY>-0.9</se:AnchorPointY>
                </se:AnchorPoint>
              </se:PointPlacement>
            </se:LabelPlacement>
            <se:Halo>
              <se:Radius>2</se:Radius>
              <se:Fill>
                <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#fafafa</se:SvgParameter>
              </se:Fill>
            </se:Halo>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#006e3c</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
          </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```